# jQuery select the appended element in an ajax call dose not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the code, .moneychoose is the div in moneychoose.jsp. $(".moneychoose") can not be selected in the ajax call.

```
$("input[name='money']").on("click", function() {
    if ($("#money").find(".moneychoose")) {
        $(".moneychoose").remove();
    }

    //append external html
    $.get("moneychoose.jsp", function (data) {
        $("#money").append(data);
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "src/province_price.json",
        data: '',
        dataType: "json",
        async: "false",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log($(".moneychoose"));
        },
        error: function(qXhr, status, error) {
            alert(status + ':' + error + ':' + qXhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

But if i add console.log($(".moneychoose")) after "append external html",
$(".moneychoose") in ajax call can be selected. why? however, the $(".moneychoose") after "append external html" still can not be selected.

```
$("input[name='money']").on("click", function() {
    if ($("#money").find(".moneychoose")) {
        $(".moneychoose").remove();
    }

    //append external html
    $.get("moneychoose.jsp", function (data) {
        $("#money").append(data);
    });

    console.log($(".moneychoose"));

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "src/province_price.json",
        data: '',
        dataType: "json",
        async: "false",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log($(".moneychoose"));
        },
        error: function(qXhr, status, error) {
            alert(status + ':' + error + ':' + qXhr.responseText);
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: You have additional `});` in end? Assuming its posting error

Comment: `if ($("#money").find(".moneychoose"))` will always be true. If you want to know if a selector finds anything, add `.length > 0`.

Comment: Your braces aren't matched properly. I wanted to fix the code indentation, but I can't do it with such invalid code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your confusion is because `console.log` is not synchronous.
Your error is because you have a race condition between two AJAX requests.

```
//append external html
$.get("moneychoose.jsp", function (data) {
  $("#money").append(data);
});
```

And

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "src/province_price.json",
        data: '',
        dataType: "json",
        async: "false",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log($(".moneychoose"));
        },
        error: function(qXhr, status, error) {
            alert(status + ':' + error + ':' + qXhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

In order to ensure that `.moneychoose` is available in the success callback of `$.ajax`, you will either need to use a Promise that resolves once both requests have succeeded, or you will need to wait to execute one of the requests until the other has finished.